# Grouping classes in packages

Tags: java, .net, package

what are best strategies to group classes in packages e.g. all managers in one package, all dao in another, would you recommend a different approach?

Any good strategies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes  with same functionality should be put in a samepackage with the package name that justify their functionality and use.

For Example:

```
your.company.app.service
```

Should contains all the service interface

```
your.company.app.service.impl
```

Should contains all the service implementation classes

```
your.company.app.utils
```

Should contains all the utility classes.

From standard API

```
java.lang   — basic language functionality and fundamental types
java.util   — collection data structure classes
java.io — file operations
java.math   — multiprecision arithmetics
java.nio    — the New I/O framework for Java
java.net    — networking operations, sockets, DNS lookups, ...
java.security   — key generation, encryption and decryption
java.sql    — Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) to access databases
java.awt    — basic hierarchy of packages for native GUI components
javax.swing — hierarchy of packages for platform-independent rich GUI components
java.applet — classes for creating an applet
```

**See**

- [Package_naming_conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions)

Comment: I'd second what Jigar said. I mean, there is no one best way to approach this, but grouping logically related items is the general way to go. Look at what java did with their core packages for example.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best one is the one that makes the code structure more clear for yourself. I usually use packages that contain classes with a similar goal. For example:

input/output
utilities
graphic_interface
src
main

But as I said, there is no best apporach.